# How to seal out of reach under-roof ledge to get rid of nested pigeon

Tags: hole

The town I just moved to has a serious pigeon problem, and I discovered they keep on loitering in and above my back courtyard, making it very dirty with their droppings.

I managed to scare almost all of them away but there is this one pigeon that just won't budge. I scare it away every 5-10 minutes when I'm home and am slowly going crazy. I suspect it has made a nest on the ledge underneath the roof above the 3rd floor.

I have access to all of the windows from the ground floor till the 3rd floor, but the ledge is at the closest 3m away.

I want to fill the ledge with something and I'm thinking of either finding a way to board it up, or to inject expansive foam up to nearly 4m away.

Any ideas on how one could achieve this?

The TLDR : How do I fill this?
(The plank is 3m long)

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Please post a photo in your question using the editor. I can't see your album. Be aware that 1) pigeon is good eating, being primarily grain-fed, and 2) many places have plenty of seasonal hunting opportunity.

Comment: Just need to view it as an opportunity: https://www.foodfanatic.com/recipes/roasted-squab/

Comment: Or enlist help: https://www.birdsoutsidemywindow.org/peregrine-faqs/peregrine-nest-box-dimensions/

Comment: @isherwood - pigeons eat whatever they can get their beaks on. Around here that's mainly garbage. They're colloquially known as 'sky rats' & as carriers of disease. They're classified as vermin. See this for an idea of just what you can catch from them… https://www.empirepestcontrol.co.uk/pigeon-control-london/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fill-in the ledge if you just prevent access to the ledge by stapling some chicken wire over it. However you arrange it, keep all parts of the chicken wire in a vertical plane or on a very steep slope so there is no place for a pigeon to land and rest on the wire.

If pigeons are roosting on a flat surface where you can't arrange chicken wire, another way to keep them off is to cover the surface with a sticky substance like Tanglefoot.

Tanglefoot looks like grease but it is extremely sticky like the coating on fly paper. It will not trap a pigeon or any bird and does not harm birds in any way. It just makes their feet sticky.

Pigeons really hate to have sticky feet, and it only takes one time landing on a patch of Tanglefoot to make them stay away. If you don't want to apply Tanglefoot directly to the surface, you can put down a strip of duct tape, then cover the duct tape with Tanglefoot.

Tanglefoot typically remains sticky for about one year, when you can re-apply it if you still have a pigeon problem. It's available in hardware stores or online.

Comment: And how does OP get the 3m across to attach it?

Comment: @Tim - carrier pigeon ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - if you carry a  pigeon, it only leaves one hand free on that plank...

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot physically get any closer, you might have some small chance of getting a strip of pigeon spikes to stick, if you can glue it, then send it out on a pole & keep it in place for a few minutes until it holds.

[image]

They are cheap & very light, & you can get them with a flat base which might give you enough chance of adhesion. Foam/fill might give you the best chance of adhesion.

Better if you could get up there with a ladder, but you might just be able to do this at a reach.

Some examples at https://www.birdspikesonline.co.uk

Shorter-term, a high-velocity water pistol or 'super-soaker' will eventually put that generation off, but new birds will re-discover it again in time.

Answer (score 0):

An internet search for "ultrasonic bird repellent" will turn up quite a number of options.

Placing one of these where you can safely reach and aiming it at the spot where you cannot might just do the trick.

*I'm not affiliated with any vendor or retailer of these products and have never used one myself. YMMV.

---

Now that I can see the image, a better solution would be to attack this from the inside under the eave. Get into the attic space and fill the hole from there. It also appears that you've got fiberglass insulation exposed in that hole which means weather is getting into your attic, causing damage to the structure. Also, the fiberglass insulation is probably a tempting target for all sorts of birds for nesting use.

Comment: The mouse type seem to be about 50/50 if they even work.  The ones we had, did not.